# How to create a unidirectional relationship where the relationship is owned by the child entity, but the parent is where the relationship is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm struggling with how to create the following relationship in JPA. It's a OneToOne Unidirectional relationship where the parent knows the child, but the child doesn't know the parent, but I want the child table to have the FK to the parent. I've tried different versions of mapped by and join column, but apparently whatever combination I come up with doesn't seem to work. And my googlefoo isn't helping me with an answer either. Here's what I have now.

```
@Entity
class Parent
{
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "child")
  private Child child
}

@Entity
class Child
{
  private bool someField
}
```

Is there a way to do this that I'm just missing?

Comment: Your annotation seems to be incorrect... `mappedBy` is the field which should be used in the reverse relation on child. The owning side of the relation should also define `@JoinColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

If this

```
@OneToOne(..)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Child child;
```

does not work, try this:

```
@OneToOne(..)
@JoinColumn(table = "child", name = "parent_id")
private Child child;
```

Comment: I tried both of those and neither seems to work, the first still puts the join column in the parent table, and the second reports that it can't find the table (and I tried different naming schemes (Class name, member name, and the actual table name)). I'm using the DDL generation to create the schema for this.

Comment: For #2, try adding @Table("child") to the Child class.

Comment: I actually already had that. @Table("some_child_table_name"), and I tried using the same thing in the @JoinColumn, but it didn't work either. I currently have a bidirectional relationship so get around the issue, not the end of the world, just makes it more difficult to deal with, and it doesn't represent what my domain model should really be.